# Is there a way to securely store files on an Android device?

Tags: java, android, security

I want to store downloaded files securely on Android device and I don't want to use encryption. How can I do it?

Can i use [Context.getDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with MOD_PRIVATE to do it ? why not ?

Comment: Are there any serious issues that prevent you from using encryption? I'm afraid, it's the only way to achieve security in this situation.

Comment: Yes, there is a serious issues that i can,t use any kind of encryption

Comment: We might be able to help you if you describe what exactly you are trying to achieve. Maybe there is something hidden in the context.

Comment: I want to download .apk file and install programmatically.

Comment: Maybe you could go more into detail what you exactly want.

Comment: i want to keep apk file safe from user ! i want to downalod apk file then run installer and after installing delete apk file. this is exactly what i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i use Context.getDir() with MOD_PRIVATE to do it ?

That directory is already private.

> I want to download .apk file and install programmatically

That is not possible, unless the installer has access to the file, which is only possible if you make the file world-readable.

Comment: so thre is no way to do that, right ?

Comment: @Armin: I do not know what "that" is, sorry.

Comment: to store apk file securely and install programmatically.

Comment: can i use Context.getDir() with MODE_WORLD_READABLE to do it??!

Comment: @Armin: Using `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` will allow the installer -- and anything else -- to read the file.

Comment: i tried iMODE_WORLD_READABLE and i got a parse error saying installer can't parse manifest.xml file.

Comment: @Armin: if you have the same problem when the file is on external storage, then the issue is the file, not where it lives.

Comment: nope i don't have the same problem.

Comment: @Armin: Hmmm... I am pretty sure that I had it working with `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` before, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

To protect data from unwanted access, you need encryption.
So, no you can't

Comment: well, i can't use any kind of encryption :(

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Sorry.

Comment: I guess i can use Context.getDir() with MOD_PRIVATE to do it. it's on phone memory which is safer than sd card and files created through a File object will only be accessible by my application.

Context.getDIr() :
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: Even if you'd do that, this is still in no way 'safe'.

Comment: There is no way around encryption if you want to have files secure. It's just a matter of principle.

Comment: yea, i think so. but i need to find a way or make a way. that's why i asked the question.

Comment: And I'm telling you there is no way except encryption of some sort.